# printf redifines UINT32_MAX

Tags: c, printf

code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdint.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    printf("%lu\n%lu\n%lu\n%lu\n%lu\n%lu\n%lu\n",
        UINT32_MAX,
        UINT32_MAX,
        UINT32_MAX,
        UINT32_MAX,
        UINT32_MAX,
        UINT32_MAX,
        UINT32_MAX);
    return 0;
}
```

output:

```
4294967295
4294967295
4294967295
4294967295
4294967295
18446744073709551615
18446744073709551615
```

bug or intentional? and why?
i think it speaks for itself but the interface needs me to add more lines before i can post it (to much code for to less text lol)

Comment: Your `printf` formats don't match the values you're passing.  Your compiler should have warned about this.  Because you're passing unexpected argument types, they are being unpacked incorrectly by `printf`.

Comment: If you're using GCC or Clang, it's a good practice to add these flags when compiling `-Wall -Wextra`. Make this an habit.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You are using `%lu`, this is incorrect.  The `%lu` specifier is for `unsigned long` and *only* `unsigned long`, not `uint32_t`.  This is why the output is incorrect.  Use `PRIu32` instead.

Your compiler should have caught this error for you, if you were compiling with warnings enabled.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdint.h>
#include <inttypes.h> // defines PRIu32

printf(
    "%" PRIu32 "\n"
    "%" PRIu32 "\n"
    "%" PRIu32 "\n"
    "%" PRIu32 "\n"
    "%" PRIu32 "\n"
    "%" PRIu32 "\n"
    "%" PRIu32 "\n",
    UINT32_MAX,
    UINT32_MAX,
    UINT32_MAX,
    UINT32_MAX,
    UINT32_MAX,
    UINT32_MAX,
    UINT32_MAX);
```

In practice, `PRIu32` is defined to `"u"` on most systems.

Comment: An alternative would be to continue using `%lu`, and to use `(unsigned long)UINT32_MAX`. This may be useful if you cannot use `<inttypes.h>` for some reason.

Comment: @Ian Abbott Need to add: casting to `(unsigned long)` is a good alternative because `unsigned long` is _at least_ the width of `uint32_t`.

Answer (score 3):

This is undefined behavior: you are passing `unsigned int`, but your `%lu` format tells `printf` that you are passing `long unsigned int`. This leads to [*undefined behavior*](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2397984/335858), because `printf` goes by what the format specifier says (in fact, it has no other way to find out, because type information is not passed to `printf`).

Once you fix your format issue, the problem goes away:

```
printf("%u\n%u\n%u\n%u\n%u\n%u\n%u\n",
    UINT32_MAX,
    UINT32_MAX,
    UINT32_MAX,
    UINT32_MAX,
    UINT32_MAX,
    UINT32_MAX,
    UINT32_MAX);
```

This prints

```
4294967295
4294967295
4294967295
4294967295
4294967295
4294967295
4294967295
```

[Demo.](http://ideone.com/Lb3kl8)

Comment: This makes the reasonable assumption that on OP's system, `uint32_t` and `unsigned` are the same type.  This is not a portable solution in general though.

Answer (score 1):

```
$ gcc -Wall -Wextra your_code.c
warning: format ‘%lu’ expects type ‘long unsigned int’, but argument 2 has type ‘unsigned int’
```

It's not a `long`, don't use the `l` specifier.

Your code has Undefined Behaviour, and in practice it essentially reads garabage.

Comment: It's not an `unsigned long`, but it's not an `unsigned int` either, so merely omitting the `l` is incorrect.

Comment: Yes, technically the minimum size for `int` is 2 bytes. Finding such a system can be tricky though ;)

Comment: @IanAbbott (replying to myself) - However, I _think_ the type of the constant `UINT32_MAX` will always be one of `unsigned int` or `unsigned long`, rather than something inbetween, so one of `%u` or `%lu` would work, but the problem is knowing which one. Hence the need for the `PRIu32` macro from `<inttypes.h>`.

Comment: I think `int` is typically 2 bytes on C compilers for 16-bit systems, such as MS-DOS (without any 32-bit extensions).

Comment: @IanAbbott: pretty much what I was saying... but who knows, perhaps MS-DOS is popular in the area you live in.